# Dynamic menu based on locations from array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, menu

I'm trying to generate a dynamic menu based on locations provided in an array of arrays.

What I'm trying to achieve:

Menu structure like this:

```
Location 1
  |_ sub-location 1
  |_ sub-location 2
      |_ floor 1
      |_ floor 2
Location 2
  |_ sub-location 1
```

etc, etc. The menu has to be dynamic as I do not know before hand which locations will be present.

The locations are provided in an array of arrays. Each array in the array contains the full path for a location, e.g.

```
[
  ["Location 1"],
  ["Location 1", "sub-location 1"],
  ["Location 1", "sub-location 2", "floor 1"]
  ["Location 1", "sub-location 2", "floor 2"]
]
```

In many cases, there will be duplicates.

I'm trying to come up with some smart way of condensing this down to some way of rendering it with React. I'm using a Menu component from Antd.

I'm struggling with getting an array to fit the model, as I don't see how to structure it in a way that allows for some arbitrary number of sub-menus and menu items.

Could it in some way be made into an object or something similar?
Still pretty new to React and javascript.

If anyone could provide some guidance, it would be super helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This structure might be more understandable and easy to work with.

```
{
    name: 'Location 1',
    sub: [
        {
            name: 'sub-location 1',
            sub: [
                { name: 'floor 1' },
                { name: 'floor 2' },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Let's call the above structure a single `menuItem`. Now you can have an array of menus like so

```
const menuItems = [menuItem1, menuItem2, ....]
```

Use this code to transform your data

```
const badMenu = [
    ['Location 1'],
    ['Location 1', 'sub-location 1'],
    ['Location 1', 'sub-location 2', 'floor 1'],
    ['Location 1', 'sub-location 2', 'floor 2'],
    ['Location 2', 'sub-location 2', 'floor 2'],
    ['Location 2', 'sub-location 2', 'floor 2'],
];

const func = (array, menu) => {
    const name = array[0];
    if (!name) {
        return;
    }

    let selected = menu.find((menuItem) => menuItem.name == name);

    if (!selected) {
        selected = { name, sub: [] };
        menu.push(selected);
    }

    func(array.slice(1), selected.sub);
};

let newMenu = [];

for (let i = 0; i < badMenu.length; i++) {
    const menuList = badMenu[i];
    func(menuList, newMenu);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(newMenu, null, 4));
```

To render this menu using `antd`:

```
const renderMenu = (menu, i) => {
    if (menu.sub && menu.sub.length) {
        return (
            <Menu.SubMenu key={menu.name + i} title={menu.name}>
                {menu.sub.map(renderMenu)}
            </Menu.SubMenu>
        );
    }
    return <Menu.Item key={menu.name + i}>{menu.name}</Menu.Item>;
};

function App() {
    return <Menu>{menu.map(renderMenu)}</Menu>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is indeed a simple structure. Now, do you have any proposal for how to convert the array of arrays into this structure?

Comment: Where are these arrays coming from? Will it be possible to save these arrays in the correct format in the first place?

Comment: unfortunately not, this is how the locations are delivered from the database. OF course duplicates needs to be removed, that's easy enough. I'm just not sure how to create a function that will generate a nice looking menu object from the array, as displayed above.

Comment: Updated the answer with the code. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: do you have a smart way of iterating through the object? I tried with a for(item of menus) recursively which kinda works, but it skips over some of the menu items.

Comment: well that was easy!!